# intellij cannot find class after cloning from github

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I am very frustrated that I cannot run my java file after cloning from github , can someone solve my problem? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Inspect the project deps and make sure they are module dependencies in IntellJ IDEA (see the project settings). If the project you cloned is Maven or Gradle driven, IDEA should pick all the dependencies itself automatically once you import the project.

Answer (score 0):

Show us the code and the screenshot isn't very clear. Try having the import statements in place